# Python - Flatten a dict of lists into unique values?

Tags: python

I have a dict of lists in python:

```
content = {88962: [80, 130], 87484: [64], 53662: [58,80]}
```

I want to turn it into a list of the unique values

```
[58,64,80,130]
```

I wrote a manual solution, but it's a manual solution.  I know there are more concise and more elegant way to do this with list comprehensions, map/reduce , itertools , etc.    anyone have a clue ?

```
content = {88962: [80, 130], 87484: [64], 53662: [58,80]}
result = set({})
for k in content.keys() :
    for i in content[k]:
        result.add(i)
# and list/sort/print just to compare the output
r2 = list( result )
r2.sort()
print r2
```

Comment: Within 3 minutes there are 4 great answers, which all prove i need to read more of the standard library docs.

Comment: *Chuckles* That feeling doesn't really ever go away - there are a *lot* of batteries included in the standard lib.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Double [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#set-displays):

Python 3:

```
sorted({x for v in content.values() for x in v})
```

Python 2:

```
sorted({x for v in content.itervalues() for x in v})
```

Comment: A link to the set comprehension documentation would make this perfect.

Comment: this is really concise and nice to look at.  You get the best answer out of sea of really excellent answers.

Comment: Note: This won't work in Python3, itervalues has been removed.

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn substitute `itervalues` for `values` in python 3 (just like you'd substitute  `iteritems` for `items` with dictionaries) since Python 3 favors lazy iteration

Comment: The answer by @Jon Clements is better at leveraging ptyhon standard libs.

Answer (score 18):

In python3.7 you can use a combination of [`.values`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values), and [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

```
from itertools import chain
sorted(set(chain(*content.values())))
# [58, 64, 80, 130]

# another option is `itertools.groupby`
from itertools import groupby
[k for k, g in groupby(sorted(chain(*content.values())))]
```

In python2.7

```
from itertools import chain
sorted(set(chain.from_iterable(content.itervalues())))
# [58, 64, 80, 130]

# another option is `itertools.groupby`
[k for k, g in groupby(sorted(chain.from_iterable(content.itervalues())))]
```

Answer (score 7):

use `set()` and `itertools.chain()`:

```
In [83]: content = {88962: [80, 130], 87484: [64], 53662: [58,80]}

In [84]: from itertools import chain

In [94]: x=set(chain(*content.values()))

In [95]: x
Out[95]: set([58, 64, 80, 130]) # a set, the items may or may not be sorted

In [96]: sorted(x)         #convert set to a sorted list
Out[96]: [58, 64, 80, 130]
```

Comment: Cool - just a couple of bits though - the `list` is redundant in `sorted(list(x))` and `*content.values()` is spelt `chain.from_iterable`...

Comment: I prefer `chain()` as it takes less amount of characters, thanks for the `sorted(list(x))` part. :)

Comment: Isn't chain.from_iterable more efficient though? Using just chain means you are unpacking the sequence. Whereas from_iterable does it in the generator.

Answer (score 4):

```
sorted(set(val
            for row in content.itervalues()
                for val in row))
```

`set` gets us all the distinct values (like a dictionary, but without the overhead of storing values).  `sorted` then just takes the created `set` and returns a `list` sorted in ascending order.

Comment: Note that this won't work in python3. Also, I think this answer explains the list comprehension a little better than the accepted answer. I like how you formatted it.

Answer (score 4):

```
list(reduce(lambda a, b: a.union(set(b)), content.itervalues(), set()))
```

The `lambda` turns the two input arguments into sets and unions them.

The `reduce` will do a [left fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_fold) over the list that is passed to it -- in this case, the lists that are the values of your dictionaries.

The `reduce` will turn the result of this, which is a `set` back into a list.

This can also be spelled:

```
list(reduce(lambda a, b: a | set(b), content.itervalues(), set()))
```

Comment: This will create a bunch of temporary sets as it loops.

Comment: Thanks!  I was editing to add some explanation and realized and (I think) fixed that.

Comment: To my eye, `a.union(set(b)` is more explicit and more readable.  `a | set (b)` certainly works as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
sorted(set(sum(content.values(), [])))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension to generate a non-unique list, convert it to a set to get the unique values, and then back into a sorted list. Perhaps not the most efficient, but yet another one line solution (this time with no imports).

Python 3:

```
sorted(list(set([val for vals in content.values() for val in vals])))
```

Python 2.7:

```
sorted(list(set([val for vals in content.itervalues() for val in vals])))
```

Comment: This should be the most elegant solution leveraging list/dictionary comprehension.